# Does someone know what is wrong with my program in c?

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault, function-call, post-increment

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int);

int main() {

    printf("%d", sum(3));

    return 0;
}

int sum(i) {

    int num = 5;

    if (num == i)
    {
        return i;
    }

    else
    {
        return i + sum(i++);
    }

}
```

This is the program, I'm getting a segmentation error
I don't know how to fix it

Comment: You have infinite recursion, because `sum(i++)` is calling `sum()` with the old value of `i`, not the incremented value. You want `sum(i+1)`.

Comment: You need to study the difference between `i++` and `++i`. Also, you can't use an auto-increment operator in the same expression where you use `i`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior

Comment: Instead of `sum(i++)` which is giving you the problem, simply use `sum(i + 1)`. Easier to read. Easier to think about.

Comment: Hi. On finding Barmar is correct I closed this question with a duplicate set explaining the logic error (post increment) and the resulting stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In C this statement

```
return i + sum(i++);
```

has undefined behavior.

Instead you need to write

```
 return i + sum( i + 1 );
```

Another problem is that the function declaration that is also its definition

```
int sum(i) {
```

is incorrect. You have to write

```
int sum(int i) {
```

Pay attention to that the function will have undefined behavior if the initial argument of the function will be greater than the magic number `5`.

Answer (score -3):

here

```
return i + sum(i++);
```

i will only be incremented *after* sum returns. So you keep recursing forever and run out of stack.

You need

```
return i + sum(++i);
```

EDIT

as other have pointer out the order of which i gets evaluated and when it gets incremented etc is not defined. SO you need

```
 ++i;
 return i + sum(i);
```

Comment: Is this now an undefined behaviour problem?

Comment: this is UB. The read of (first) `i` and the write of (the 2nd) `i` are not sequenced.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I k=now understand the comment thanks to bolov

Comment: note that even in the case of `return sum(i++);`,  `i` would be incremented before `sum` returns (and in fact, before `sum` is entered). There is a sequence point on entry to a function, after evaluation of arguments